# Email from a single external user isn't received by a single internal user in our domain

Tags: email, email-server, exchange-2007, outlook, windows-sbs-2008

We have internal users with @companyx.co.nz email addresses on the domain.

We have an external company who use @externalcompany.co.nz.

A single user on our domain (sam@companyx.co.nz) can't seem to receive messages from a single user on the external domain (bill@externalcompany.co.nz).

However, Bill (ext) can send to other users on our domain (int). And other members of the external domain/company can send to Sam (int) fine and others on our domain.

Bill (ext) receives no bounce back or errors.

SBS 2008 running Exchange 2007.

I've logged into OWA offsite as Sam to check that it's not just their Outlook software onsite filtering out the sender or some other reason but the message doesn't display in OWA either.

There is a forwarder setup from Sam to Alan (keeps copy in Sam's mailbox) and when Bill sends an email to both Sam and Alan, Sam does not receive it, Alan does.

Where would one look next?

Thank you.

Comment: Use the Message Tracking and Tracking Log Explorer tools to track a message from the external sender to the internal recipient.

Comment: Thankfully it's enabled and I've found the log location but the latest logs are yesterdays. Are the logs not available until the next day? What would be a good way to test? Have the sender send a message to Sam and then email myself notifying me of the time it was sent? Then looking at that days log the following day for that time and seeing what I find? Sorry I haven't used these Exchange logs before :)

Comment: The logs should be updating in real time. Look in the message tracking directory and verify that you have at least one log file for the current day.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start 1/1/14 -resultsize unlimited -sender 'bill@externalcompany.co.nz' -Recipients 'sam@companyx.co.nz'
```

and

```
Get-AgentLog -StartDate 1/1/14 | Where-Object {$_.recipients -like 'sam@companyx.co.nz' -and $_.p2fromaddresses -like 'bill@externalcompany.co.nz'}
```

in the Exchange Management Shell and see if either of those provide any enlightenment.

Comment: Thank you I will try and run these today or tomorrow - what specifically will I be looking for in the results? Thank you.

Comment: The top one will hopefully show the mail from bill@externalcompany.co.nz and to sam@companyx.co.nz hitting your server, and whether it was stored or rejected.  The bottom one will hopefully provide a reason why it was rejected, if it was.

Comment: Is there somewhere to attach the results?

Too long to post in the comments box.

Comment: Pastebin?  Or you could edit your question.

Comment: Hah, never knew about pastebin! Cool!

http://pastebin.com/HKZe7CeQ

Comment: Okay.  What that's telling you is that it's arriving, and Exchange is routing it and delivering it to Sam.  So it's getting that far.  Does Sam have any server-side rules that might be affecting this mail?

Comment: How come it has REDIRECT and TRANSFER events for Sam but for Alan (who would have been CC'd or addressee and Sam CC'd) it shows RECEIVE and that's it? I'll check with Sam shortly to see if Sam has rules on their Outlook that may be affecting the incoming mail. As far as I'm aware Sam does not.

Comment: D'oh.  I was expecting to see an EventID of FAIL.  Redirect - A message was redirected to an alternative recipient after an Active Directory lookup.  Transfer - Recipients were moved to a forked message because of content conversion, message recipient limits, or agents. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124375(v=exchg.150).aspx#EventTypes  Run this, too:  `Get-Mailbox <identity> | fl ForwardingAddress,DeliverToMailboxandForward`  to see if there's a forward on his mail.

Comment: Ah, yes, there is a forwarder from Sam to Alan who was the CC or the direct addressee in the actual emails. Now because Sam forwards (copies) mail to Alan and Alan is one of the recipients on the message(s) that Sam is missing would that cause an issue and cause the mail to not be delivered to Sam?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12967/discussion-between-katherine-villyard-and-logan)

Comment: Yes, the default behavior is to forward and not retain.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351134(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Sorry I'm just about to finish work for the day so unable to begin a chat session. The forwarder has been setup to still deliver to Sam and copy to Alan. What happens when someone sends to Alan *AND* Sam but Sam has a fowarder setup to *COPY* mail to Alan? Mail only gets delivered to Alan? Shouldn't it still be delivered to both? Seems like a pretty silly thing if it doesn't get delivered to the person with the forwarder setup.

Comment: Unable to chat due to reputation not meeting the required level. Could you please write your response to my previous comment? I understand the default is to forward and not retain, but it's been setup to forward AND retain, so unsure why mail from this particular user isn't getting delivered to Sam but is to Alan.

Comment: Hello Katherine Villyard are you still able to assist? Alan is the director of the company and Sam is in accounts so it is important they both receive mail from this individual (from a financial institution).